# Merging File and Post data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, file, post

At work I've been dealing with some complex forms (publish pages of [Symphony](http://symphony-cms.com/)) that contain multiple image upload fields. I need a way to quickly merge `$_FILES` with `$_POST`, unfortunately you cannot simply merge the two with `array_merge` because they don't follow the same structure.

Basically if you have `$_POST[a][b]` it would be `$_FILES[a][*][b]`. Replace `*` with one of `name`, `type`, `tmp_name`, `error` or `size`.

The content of the `$_FILES` array as standard:

```
array
  'image-a' => array
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'image-b' => array
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'image' => array
      'name' => array
          'sub' => array
              'c' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => array
          'sub' => array
              'c' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => array
          'sub' => array
              'c' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => array
          'sub' => array
              'c' => int 4
      'size' => array
          'sub' => array
              'c' => int 0
```

And the desired array after merging with `$_POST`:

```
array
  'MAX_FILE_SIZE' => string '5242880' (length=7)
  'image-a' => array
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'image-b' => array
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'image' => array
      'sub' => array
          'c' => array
              'name' => string '' (length=0)
              'type' => string '' (length=0)
              'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
              'error' => int 4
              'size' => int 0
```

Comment: then it should be community wiki...

Comment: gnarf, that doesn't work because for historical reasons `$_FILES` has a structure different to `$_POST`.

Comment: Oh wait - nevermind - I see the difference you refer to now.. The Hierarcial pattern for $_FILES is odd for sure... Removing my earlier comments, and adding a var_dump of the `$_FILES` array from your example.

Comment: Not quite, the first level matches, however the second level does not, so if you have `$_POST[a][b]` it would be `$_FILES[a][...][b]`. Replace `...` with one of `name`, `type`, `tmp_name`, `error` or `size`.

Comment: In order to make this more of a Question, you should probably reword/edit it to state that problem upfront showing the actual input, and desired format, then feel free to post an answer to your own question with your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with, calling `get_file_post_data` returns the merged array:

```
<?php

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        header('content-type: text/plain');

        function merge_file_post_data($type, $file, &$post) {
            foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
                if (!isset($post[$key])) $post[$key] = array();
                if (is_array($value)) merge_file_post_data($type, $value, $post[$key]);
                else $post[$key][$type] = $value;
            }
        }

        function get_file_post_data() {
            $files = array(
                'name'        => array(),
                'type'        => array(),
                'tmp_name'    => array(),
                'error'        => array(),
                'size'        => array()
            );
            $post = $_POST;

            // Flip the first level with the second:
            foreach ($_FILES as $key_a => $data_a) {
                foreach ($data_a as $key_b => $data_b) {
                    $files[$key_b][$key_a] = $data_b;
                }
            }

            // Merge and make the first level the deepest level:
            foreach ($files as $type => $data) {
                merge_file_post_data($type, $data, $post);
            }

            return $post;
        }

        var_dump(get_file_post_data());
    }

    else echo '
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="5242880">
            <div><label class="file">Image A <input name="image-a" type="file"></label></div>
            <div><label class="file">Image B <input name="image-b" type="file"></label></div>
            <div><label class="file">Image C <input name="image[sub][c]" type="file"></label></div>
            <div><button type="submit">Send</button></div>
        </form>
    ';

?>
```