# nothing displayed in php response header after sending multipart form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following files. Nothing is displayed in the Response header of developer tools. I am expecting the variables related to files and post in my `accept.php` page.

I can see `console.log(formData);` getting printed but `console.log(returndata);`

1) `send.php` file

```
<?php

echo ' 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>

<form id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" readonly="readonly">
      User Name: <input type="text" name="username" value=""><br />
      Profile Image: <input name="profileImg[]" type="file" /><br />
      Display Image: <input name="displayImg[]" type="file" /><br />
      <button  type = "button" onclick="submitFileTest()">Submit Button  </button>
    </form>';

?>
```

2) `file.js`

```
function submitFileTest() { 


          //grab all form data  
          var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

          console.log("Form Data Test");
          console.log(formData);

          $.ajax({
            url: 'accept.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (returndata) {
              //alert(returndata);
              console.log(returndata);
            }
          });




 }
```

3) `accept.php`

```
<?php


        if (isset($_POST['id'])) {                      
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            var_dump($id);
            echo $id;
        }


        if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
           $username = $_POST['username'];
           var_dump($username);
           echo $username;
        }


        if (isset($_FILES['profileImg'])) {
            $profileImg = $_FILES['profileImg'];
            var_dump($profileImg);
            echo $profileImg;
        }

        if (isset($_FILES['displayImg'])) {
             $displayImg = $_FILES['displayImg'];
             var_dump($displaying);
             echo $displayImg;
        }

?>
```

**TESTING RESULTS (after using Popmedic answer):**

Before testing, for `displayImg`,I changed the file array value in the following line `formData.append('displayImg', $('input[type=file]')[1].files[0]);` from `0` to `1` as shown below `formData.append('displayImg', $('input[type=file]')[1].files[1]);`

I am able to see the `id` value, `username` value and `profileImg` value in my php script as shown in the screenshot of console window of IE11 below. But for some reason, the code is not picking up the second file which is `displayImg`.

[image]

The following is the screenshot of `Request body` of IE11 showing that for the file `displayImg`, there is nothing present.

[image]

**Clarifications on Popmedic's comments (April 18):**

I have merged the POST and FILEs results using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371544/merging-file-and-post-data-in-php) and got the following in the JSON format:

```
{"id":"123","username":"123","profileImg":{"name":"Request_body.PNG","type":"image\/png","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpA981.tmp","error":0,"size":15842},"displayImg":{"name":"Request_body.PNG","type":"image\/png","tmp_name":"C:\\wamp\\tmp\\phpA9A1.tmp","error":0,"size":15842}}
```

I already have a Java webservice working which is accepting a JSON object and storing it in the Oracle database in the form of CLOB. So that's the reason I merged and converted into JSON as shown above. I would like to include the variable `$str` value also in the JSON response above obtained from this line of code`$str = file_get_contents($_FILES["displayImg"]["tmp_name"]);` so that in addition to the above JSON, I could also include the file contents to the webservice and that Java webservice will make sure that it's inserted into the Oracle database. eventually my cuRL request would look like this:

```
                      $curl = curl_init();
                      curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                      CURLOPT_PORT => "9090",
                      CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:9090/myJavaWebservice/rest/somepath/insertDataToDB",
                      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $_POST["myData"],
                      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Content-Type: application/json"

                        ),
                      ));

                    $response_post_march22 = curl_exec($curl);
                    $err = curl_error($curl);

                    curl_close($curl);

                    if ($err) {
                      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
                    } else {
                      echo $response_post_march22;
                    }
```

I already have the above curl request working and inserting the data into the database but now instead of `myData` which is a `JSON object`, I would be passing the new JSON, I created above after merging including the file content obtained using the `$str` variable so that everything can be stored into the database.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this? It should be fairly easy to inspect what is sent to the webserver through your browser's developer tools

Comment: Are there any errors in your PHP-logs?

Comment: @NicoHaase Response header is blank as I mentioned in my post. I can see `accept.php` under  network tab. What else I should be looking at?

Comment: try handling your error in the `.ajax` call as well. ie: `$.ajax({...error: function(xhr,status,error){...}...})`

Comment: You could check which elements are sent to the server in the developer console, and after all, you don't set any header in `accept.php`, so where should they come from?

Comment: BTW you do see that displaying is not defined for: `var_dump($displaying)` and you know you don't need to echo your html in send.php, just put the html outside the `<?php ?>` section...

Comment: @Popmedic I corrected the `var_dump($displaying);` to `var_dump($displayImg);`, also moved the HTML outside php tags. Also, I included ` alert("Returndata"+returndata);` inside success function and I could see `Returndata    ` alert pop-up. Still I don't see any variables in developers tools.

Comment: what browser's developers tools?

Comment: @Popmedic chrome

Comment: this might help with understanding how to return those images... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633908/php-display-image-with-header ... you will have to set the content-type, content-length, ...

Comment: Thanks but I will be sending PDF and Docs eventually instead of Images.

Comment: I think it is that it is not responding at all, check the pup logs to see what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe set something in the header for you to see...

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {                      
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    header ("ID: $id");
    var_dump($id);
    echo $id;
}else {
    header ("ID-Present: Nope");
}


if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    header ("User-Name: $username");
    var_dump($username);
    echo $username;
}else {
    header ("User-Name-Present: Nope");
}


if (isset($_FILES['profileImg'])) {
    $profileImg = $_FILES['profileImg'];
    header ("Profile-Image-Present: Yep");
    var_dump($profileImg);
    echo $profileImg;
} else {
    header ("Profile-Image-Present: Nope");
}

if (isset($_FILES['displayImg'])) {
    $displayImg = $_FILES['displayImg'];
    header ("Display-Image-Present: Yep");
    var_dump($displayImg);
    echo $displayImg;
} else {
    header ("Display-Image-Present: Nope");
}
```

**UPDATED TO SHOW HOW TO SET QUERY PARAM(S)**

If you want the headers to be something other then "Nope," you need to send those values in your javascript AJAX request like so:

```
function submitFileTest() { 
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', $('[name="id"]').val());
    formData.append('username', $('[name="username"]').val());
    // Attach file
    formData.append('profileImg', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    formData.append('displayImg', $('input[type=file]')[1].files[0]); 
    console.log("Form Data Test");
    console.log(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'accept.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (returndata) {
          //alert(returndata);
          console.log(returndata);
        }
      });
}
```

**UPDATED TO USE `get_file_post_data` FROM OTHER [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371544/merging-file-and-post-data-in-php)**

I believe if you change the [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371544/merging-file-and-post-data-in-php) `get_file_post_data` function (I had to remove some of the useless code from this function, it annoyed me too much) to:

```
function get_file_post_data() {
    $files = array();
    $post = $_POST;
    foreach ($_FILES as $key_a => $data_a) 
        foreach ($data_a as $key_b => $data_b) {
            // Add this --->
            if ($key_b == 'tmp_name')
                $files['data'][$key_a] = base64_encode(file_get_contents($data_b));
            // <--- end
            $files[$key_b][$key_a] = $data_b;
        }
    foreach ($files as $type => $data) merge_file_post_data($type, $data, $post);
    return $post;
}
```

Then when you convert into JSON with something like `json_encode(get_file_post_data(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`, you will have JSON like so:

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "username": "kevin",
    "profileImg": {
        "name": "suggestions@1.png",
        "type": "image\/png",
        "data": "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",
        "tmp_name": "\/private\/var\/tmp\/phpBU7D0c",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 941
    },
    "displayImg": {
        "name": "suggestions@2.png",
        "type": "image\/png",
        "data": "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",
        "tmp_name": "\/private\/var\/tmp\/php3kezNJ",
        "error": 0,
        "size": 1635
    }
}
```

If you would like to cut the response time in about half, you can try doing some [poorman's threading](https://github.com/popmedic/php-background_file_upload) in PHP...